# Reemplazar valor null de array por 0

Tags: javascript

tengo un problema, tengo un array que tiene ciertos valores null, quisiera cambiar todos los valores null por 0, intente con .replace pero no me salio.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi codigo, el array original lo traigo desde PHP, necesitaria recorrer el array y remplazar los valores null por 0

```
    $.ajax({
    url: 'STATS/metas.php',
    type: 'GET',
    dateType: 'text',
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response)
        let metas = JSON.parse(response)
        console.log(metas)
        let cultivo = metas[0].totalCultivado
        let cosecha = metas[0].totalCosechado
        let diferencia = metas[0].diferencia
        let metasChicas = metas[0].metasChicas
        let metasMedianas = metas[0].metasMedianas
        let cultivoKG = metas[0].KGcultivados
        let cultivoATADO = metas[0].ATADOScultivados
        let cultivoUNIDAD = metas[0].UNIDADEScultivadas
        let cosechaKG = metas[0].KGcosechados
        let cosechaATADO = metas[0].ATADOScosechados
        let cosechaUNIDAD = metas[0].UNIDADEScosechadas
        
        $('#m1').html(cultivo)
        $('#kgCultivos').html(cultivoKG + " kg")
        $('#atadoCultivos').html(cultivoATADO + " atados")
        $('#unidadCultivos').html(cultivoUNIDAD + " unidades")
        $('#m2').html(cosecha)
        $('#kgCosechado').html(cosechaKG + " kg")
        $('#atadoCosechado').html(cosechaATADO + " atados")
        $('#unidadCosechado').html(cosechaUNIDAD + " unidades")

    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer, no es un arreglo el que tiene valores nulos, sino un objeto en la posición 0 de tu arreglo, así que lo que debes hacer es usar Object.keys, que te retorna dentro de un arreglo todas las llaves de un objeto, e iterar ese arreglo para reemplazar en tu objeto los valores que estén en nulo.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "STATS/metas.php",
  type: "GET",
  dateType: "text",
  success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    let metas = JSON.parse(response);
    console.log(metas);

    Object.keys(metas[0]).forEach((key) => {
      if (metas[0][key] === null) {
        metas[0][key] = 0;
      }
    });

    let cultivo = metas[0].totalCultivado;
    let cosecha = metas[0].totalCosechado;
    let diferencia = metas[0].diferencia;
    let metasChicas = metas[0].metasChicas;
    let metasMedianas = metas[0].metasMedianas;
    let cultivoKG = metas[0].KGcultivados;
    let cultivoATADO = metas[0].ATADOScultivados;
    let cultivoUNIDAD = metas[0].UNIDADEScultivadas;
    let cosechaKG = metas[0].KGcosechados;
    let cosechaATADO = metas[0].ATADOScosechados;
    let cosechaUNIDAD = metas[0].UNIDADEScosechadas;

    $("#m1").html(cultivo);
    $("#kgCultivos").html(cultivoKG + " kg");
    $("#atadoCultivos").html(cultivoATADO + " atados");
    $("#unidadCultivos").html(cultivoUNIDAD + " unidades");
    $("#m2").html(cosecha);
    $("#kgCosechado").html(cosechaKG + " kg");
    $("#atadoCosechado").html(cosechaATADO + " atados");
    $("#unidadCosechado").html(cosechaUNIDAD + " unidades");
  },
});
```

Comment: ahh, genial bro, era eso, me exprese mal, perdon, pero tu solucion funciono, gracias